# Update php config from a php script

Tags: php

I'm extending an application that stores configuration data in a php file. The file looks like this:

```
defined('DB_NAME') or define('DB_NAME', '');
defined('DB_USERNAME') or define('DB_USERNAME', '');
defined('DB_PASSWORD') or define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
```

Say, I want to make the parameter *DB_NAME* configurable from within the php application itself, thus avoiding manual changes in config.php. I thought of reading the file, searching for the string 'DB_NAME', do some string manipulation, and write the content back. However, this does not seem very elegant. Is there any other way?

Comment: Use a configuration file class implementation.

Comment: I'm no expert, but what stops you from receiving the variable from a POST and then setting it with define() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it:

- Copy the entire config in a config.tpl, to be used as a template
- alter it to contain unique placeholders like this:
  `defined('DB_NAME') or define('DB_NAME', '%DB_NAME%');`
- write a class of function which replaces placeholders with values in the template and writes to disk as config.php

The only thing to take care of is unique placeholders

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you avoid PHP source code and switch to any standard data format where you already have encoders and decoders. There's a lot to choose from:

- [XML](http://php.net/simplexml)
- [JSON](http://php.net/json_encode)
- [INI](http://php.net/parse_ini_file)
- [YAML](http://php.net/yaml)
- SQL and no-SQL databases...

Comment: This is definitely how I will do it in my own projects in the future!